# Sonar Analyzer Test Code Issues not shown

Tags: typescript, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarcloud, sast

I had my SonarQube code analysis setup and it work realy well, it also shows my test code, but it is not showing the issues in my test code.
To test this, i build some `// TODO:` tasks in my test code and they are not reported as Issues in SonarQube.
Has anyone a idea what is wrong in my `sonar-project.properties`

Here is my config:

```yaml
# Source File Inclusions/Exclusions
sonar.sources=apps,libs,packages,tools,e2e
sonar.inclusions=**/*.js,**/*.ts,**/*.mjs,**/*.scss,**/*.html
sonar.exclusions=**/jest.config.js,**/cypress.config.ts,**/test-setup.ts,**/jest.config.ts

# Test File Inclusions/Exclusions
sonar.tests=apps,libs,packages,tools,e2e
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.spec.ts,**/*.mock.ts,**/*.cy.ts,e2e/**/*.*
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov_unit.info
sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=coverage/test-report.xml

sonar.coverage.exclusions=tools/**/*.*

# Housekeeping
sonar.dbcleaner.hoursBeforeKeepingOnlyOneSnapshotByDay=72
sonar.dbcleaner.weeksBeforeKeepingOnlyOneSnapshotByWeek=8
sonar.dbcleaner.weeksBeforeKeepingOnlyOneSnapshotByMonth=52
sonar.dbcleaner.weeksBeforeKeepingOnlyAnalysesWithVersion=104
sonar.dbcleaner.weeksBeforeDeletingAllSnapshots=260
sonar.dbcleaner.daysBeforeDeletingClosedIssues=30

# Other Settings
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.verbose=true
```

Comment: Uh, have u found the solution for this problem? I am on same point and haven't seen any solution for it :/

Comment: @burgua sry no I still looking for a solution that solves my problem